# How do I implement Copy and Clone for a type that contains a String (or any type that doesn't implement Copy)?

Tags: rust

I have an enum in Rust which has one value that takes a `String`:

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
enum Simple {
    Error(String),
    Okay,
    Foo([u32; 5]),
}

fn main() {
    let x = Simple::Error(String::from("blah"));
    let y = x.clone();
}
```

The enum value `Foo` above represents about 10 other enums I use that take copyable types or arrays of them. The compiler doesn't seem to complain about them, only the `Error(String)` which causes this:

```
error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
 --> src/main.rs:1:17
  |
1 | #[derive(Clone, Copy)]
  |                 ^^^^
2 | enum Simple {
3 |     Error(String),
  |           ------ this field does not implement `Copy`
  |
```

For some reason, `String` is not copyable. I don't get this. How do I implement `Clone` for an enum for just the one type which has a problem while using the default impl for the rest?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

#### Copy

[`Copy`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) designates types for which making a bitwise copy creates a valid instance without invalidating the original instance.

This isn't true for [`String`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html), because `String` contains a pointer to the string data on the heap and assumes it has unique ownership of that data. When you drop a `String`, it deallocates the data on the heap. If you had made a bitwise copy of a `String`, then both instances would try to deallocate the same memory block, which is *undefined behaviour*.

Since `String` doesn't implement `Copy`, **your `enum` cannot implement `Copy` either** because the compiler enforces that `Copy` types are composed only of `Copy` data members.

#### Clone

[`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) merely provides a standard `clone` method, and it's up to each implementor to decide how to implement it. `String` does implement `Clone`, so you *can* put `#[derive(Clone)]` on your `enum`.

Comment: I should add I don't see why String can't implement a Copy trait in principle or practice - QString objects in QT can be copied and they share and maintain an internal buffer. If a copy does something mutable the buffer is first cloned so other copies still hold a reference to the original buffer. In QT it's still better practice to pass by reference to avoid atomic ref counting but copy is efficient anyway.

Comment: @locka because *`Copy` designates types for which making a bitwise copy  creates a valid instance*. Copying the bits of such a string could not increment an atomic counter, because it wouldn't be copying anymore. You get to choose what guarantees you need. You can [share ownership](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html), [share ownership across threads](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), implement [clone on write](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), etc. It would not be good for a systems language to make that decision (and burden your code) for you.

Comment: What does it mean by `bitwise copy`?

Comment: @cakraww `bitwise copy` is a shallow copy of all bytes using `memcpy` or similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749439/what-is-the-difference-between-memberwise-copy-bitwise-copy-shallow-copy-and-d

Comment: @locka A type that requires allocation cannot be `Copy` because only a single deallocation may be performed or else you get a double free. If you could copy Strings, which instance would be responsible for deallocating the buffer? What you're describing is basically `Cow<str>` or `Rc<str>`, which also can't be `Copy` for the same reason: you need to correctly call `drop` to manage the buffer and eventually deallocate it.

Answer (score 10):

I did some exploring to see what a manual implementation would look like for an enum. I came up with this, but keep in mind you can also do `#[derive(Clone)]` as stated elsewhere and the compiler will do this for you.

```
enum Simple {
    Error(String),
    Okay,
    Foo([u32; 5]),
}

impl Clone for Simple {
    fn clone(&self) -> Simple {
        match self {
            Error(a) => Error(a.to_string()),
            Okay => Okay,
            Foo(a) => Foo(a.clone()),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum ServerResponse {
    Ok(String),
    Err(String),
}` I get `error[E0204]: the trait 'Copy' may not be implemented for this type`  `Ok(String),
   |        ------ this field does not implement 'Copy'`. Implementing Copy manually leads to a similar error.