# How can str be copied if it doesn't implement the Copy trait?

Tags: rust, traits, primitive

"The `str` type, also called a 'string slice', is the most *primitive* [emphasis added] string type." (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html)

Intuitively `str` should therefore be copiable, which it is:

```
fn main() {
    let _str = "hello";
    let _str2 = _str;

    println!("{}", _str); // Output: hello
}
```

However, it does not implement the `Copy` trait:

```
fn main() {
    is_copy::<str>(); // Compile time error: the trait std::marker::Copy is not implemented for str
}

fn is_copy<T: Copy>() {}
```

What allows this copy-like behaviour with `str`?

Comment: does this answer your qu? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215753/how-do-i-implement-copy-and-clone-for-a-type-that-contains-a-string read the comments too

Comment: `Copy` is implemented for all reference `&str`

Comment: You may be confused about the term "primitive". That `str` is primitive means it is built in to the language on a fundamental level, which `str` is. It does not imply `Copy`. `&mut` references are also primitive types that are not `Copy`.

Comment: All of this is useful information but the accepted answer is what I sought.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`"abc"` is *more* than *just* a `str`. It is in fact a reference:

```
fn name_of_val<T>(_: T) {
    println!("{:?}", std::any::type_name::<T>());
}
name_of_val("abc");
//Prints "&str".
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d5b4af97634a1a772569f4c8c5ba6cf6).

Therefore, we can't look at the `str` implementations directly, instead we must look at the [`&T` (Reference)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.reference.html) implementations of traits.

We have a copy impl:

```
impl<'_, T> Copy for &'_ T
where
    T: ?Sized;
```

This satisfies `&str`. But since `str` is unsized, we cannot impl copy for it, since it is the data in a string, not a pointer/reference/`(size, ptr)` to it. We could therefore not do a bitwise [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html) of the `str` since we wouldn't know how much data to copy.

Comment: is `"abc"` a reference, or is the temporary variable that points to it a reference?

Comment: `"abc"`, in rust, has the type `&str`, meaning it is a reference. The actual bytes that make up the UTF8 compliant string we know and love as abc are the `str` which are stored in the binary. You cannot pass an unsized bit of data around if it's not under some kind of indirection which can manage it appropriately.