# How to implement copy trait for my custom struct ( linked list ) and how to loop through linked list in one function call

Tags: rust, linked-list, iterator

This is my whole code

Aim : to delete link from linked list via looping inside delete() function unlike in push() function ( used recurrsion ).

`Error`

```
error[E0204]: the trait `Copy` may not be implemented for this type
 --> first.rs:3:24
  |
3 | #[derive(Clone, Debug, Copy)]
  |                        ^^^^
...
7 |     Node { data: T, next: Box<Link<T>> },
  |                     ------------------ this field does not implement `Copy`
  |
  = note: this error originates in the derive macro `Copy` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

```
use std::fmt::Display;
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Copy)]
enum Link<T> {
    None,
    Tail { data: T },
    Node { data: T, next: Box<Link<T>> },
}
enum MyError {
    NotFound,
}
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Cursor<T> {
    curr: Link<T>,
}
impl<T> Cursor<T> {
    fn new(curr: Link<T>) -> Self {
        Self { curr }
    }
}
#[allow(dead_code)]
impl<T> Link<T>
where
    T: Clone + Copy + std::cmp::PartialEq + Display,
{
    fn delete(&mut self, d: T) -> Result<T, MyError> {
        /* not fully logically impemented , deleting last link `may` work , didnt implement to the middle links */
        let mut iter: Cursor<T> = self.into_iter();
        let res = loop {
            // println!("val = {}", iter.curr.data);
            match iter.curr {
                Link::Node { data, ref next } => {
                    println!("val = {}", data);
                }
                Link::None => (),
                Link::Tail { data } => {
                    println!("val = {}", data);
                }
            }
            match iter.curr {
                Link::None => Err(MyError::NotFound),
                Link::Tail { data } => {
                    if d == data {
                        iter.curr.pop();
                        break Ok(d);
                    }
                    break Err(MyError::NotFound);
                }
                Link::Node { data, ref next } => Ok({
                    if d == data {
                        break Ok(d);
                    }
                    iter.next();
                }),
            };
        };
        res
    }
    fn new() -> Link<T> {
        Link::None
    }
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        match self {
            Link::None => None,
            Link::Tail { data } => {
                let d = *data;
                self.to_none();
                Some(d)
            }
            Link::Node { data: _, next } => next.pop(),
        }
    }
    fn push(&mut self, d: T) {
        match self {
            Link::None => self.to_tail(d),
            Link::Tail { .. } => self.to_link(d),
            Link::Node { next, .. } => next.push(d),
        }
    }
    fn push_front(&mut self, d: T) {
        *self = Link::Node {
            data: d,
            next: Box::new(self.clone()),
        };
    }
    fn to_link(&mut self, d: T) {
        *self = match self {
            Link::Tail { data: d1 } => Link::Node {
                data: *d1,
                next: Box::new(Link::Tail { data: d }),
            },
            _ => panic!("pucked2"),
        }
    }
    fn to_next(&mut self, nxt: Link<T>) {
        *self = nxt;
    }
    fn to_none(&mut self) {
        *self = match self {
            Link::None => todo!(),
            Link::Tail { .. } => Link::None,
            Link::Node { .. } => todo!(),
        }
    }
    fn to_tail(&mut self, d: T) {
        *self = match self {
            Link::None => Link::Tail { data: d },
            _ => panic!("pucked1"),
        }
    }
}

impl<T> IntoIterator for Link<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    type Item = T;

    type IntoIter = Cursor<T>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        Cursor::new(self)
    }
}

impl<T> Iterator for Cursor<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let next = match self.curr {
            Link::None => None,
            Link::Tail { data } => {
                self.curr = Link::None;
                Some(data)
            }
            Link::Node { data, ref mut next } => {
                let mut n = Box::new(Link::None);
                std::mem::swap(next, &mut n);
                self.curr = *n;
                Some(data)
            }
        };
        next
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut list: Link<i32> = Link::new();
    // let mut list2: Link<i32> = Link::new();

    list.push(1);
    list.push(2);
    list.push(3);
    list.push(4);
    // println!("{:?}", list.pop());
    list.delete(3);
    for i in list.clone() {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to implement `Copy` since `Box` does not implement `Copy`. What is the error you get when you remove `Copy` from `#[derive(...)]`? Perhaps someone could provide an alternative.

Comment: Fair warning: Rust hates linked lists. [Here's](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) a good introduction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I implement Copy and Clone for a type that contains a String (or any type that doesn't implement Copy)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215753/how-do-i-implement-copy-and-clone-for-a-type-that-contains-a-string-or-any-type)

Comment: What is my main intention was to delete a link from the linked list using a for loop or while loop using iterators ( into_iter() ), but when I call into iter its giving error **move occurs because `*self` has type `Link<T>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait** 
for now, I'm using as `self.clone().into_iter()` bus this don't reflect changes in `self` 
I need implementation code for deleting a node from linked list.