# How can we initialize a BigDecimal array in Rust?

Tags: rust

I wanted to have an array of BigDecimal values, as I know the size ahead of time and it is constant.

I cannot figure out how it could be initialized in Rust however. This method:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct BigArray { values: [BigDecimal; 52] }
fn main() {
    let mut v = BigArray { values: [BigDecimal::from_str("0"); 52] };
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

yields the following error:

> the trait `Copy` is not implemented for `BigDecimal`
>
> note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied

I do want the default BigDecimal value to be cloned across the array.

Is it impossible to do? Is Vec the only option?

*I can [turn it into a borrowed value](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=819b5774ac6d1a113f69277265cf5bb7) but then it is no longer a BigDecimal array, and lifetime management and dangling pointers become quite hairy.*

[Rust playground snippet](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff4f3991bd02cc2ea4bf8746cba49acc).

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215753/how-do-i-implement-copy-and-clone-for-a-type-that-contains-a-string-or-any-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can  dynamically create a vec and then transform it into the array:

```rust
// --- Fake BigDecimal library for testing purposes.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct BigDecimal {
    str: String,
}
impl BigDecimal {
    fn from_str(str: &str) -> BigDecimal {
        BigDecimal {
            str: String::from(str),
        }
    }
}

// --- Code that is actually under test.
#[derive(Debug)]
struct BigArray {
    values: [BigDecimal; 10],
}
fn main() {
    let mut v = BigArray {
        values: (0..10)
            .map(|_| BigDecimal::from_str("0"))
            .collect::<Vec<_>>()
            .try_into()
            .unwrap(),
    };
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=96836879b27eb9262fd8b578e69ef130)

Or using [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.array.html#method.map):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = BigArray {
        values: [(); 10].map(|_| BigDecimal::from_str("0"))
    };
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1bc7c47883967d9932a7d68e076f3faa)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works outstandingly well. The second solution is quite elegant, too!